# Maintain more than 50 digits in c++

Tags: c++, integer, biginteger

Please tell me how I can store more than 50 digits in c ++.
You might say that this question was asked and use the string. But I want the "plus", "minus" and "or" operations to be performed on this stored data.

Comment: Use an array or a vector. You know how to do plus and minus -- you learned it it grade school. One digit at a time.

Comment: Primitive data types and CPU instructions aren't capable of handling such large values. As such, you need to store the digits inside of a string or inside a vector of integers and perform arithmetic on top of them. If you want operator support, you can [overload them by wrapping them inside a class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). There are several arbitrary precision libraries for C++ on the web, just a quick google search will lead you to one. One of the well-known ones is [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) and you can use its C++ wrapper if you want operator support.

Comment: Use a string.  Implement the **plus**, **minus**, and **or** operations for your numeric string.

Comment: @Eljay: I wouldn't recommend implementing it as a string if bitwise-or operations are desired (which is what OP is explicitly asking for).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel • yeah, probably beyond the scope of the question to implement decimal-value **or** logic based on Kleene, Priest, Bochvar, Belnap, Gödel, Łukasiewicz, et al.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bigint implementation in the standard library. 50 decimals will require 166 bit. And the largest primitive type is `std::uint64_t`. Even if you have a 128 bit extension, it will do you no good because you are still a few bits short.

If you need such large numbers to be precise you have to roll your own bigint type or search for a library that supports it (boost likely has one).

If you don't need absolute precision and can do the bitwise or, you can use one of the floating point types, e.g. `double`.

Comment: Floating-point types do not support bitwise-or operations, which is one of the operations that OP is explicitly asking for.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Good point. However, possibly OP means "boolean or"? Anyhow I modified the line about floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by bitmask there is no bigint in std in c++ as of now. But we can implement a Bigint structure on our own, although it will increase the complexity of the operations.

```
/*
  ######################################################################
  #######################   THE   BIG   INT   ##########################
*/

const int base = 1000000000;
const int base_digits = 9;

struct Int
{

    vector<int> a;
    int sign;

    /*<arpa>*/

    int size()
    {
        if (a.empty())
            return 0;
        int ans = (a.size() - 1) * base_digits;
        int ca = a.back();
        while (ca)
            ans++, ca /= 10;
        return ans;
    }

    Int operator^(const Int &v)
    {
        Int ans = 1, a = *this, b = v;
        while (!b.isZero())
        {
            if (b % 2)
                ans *= a;
            a *= a, b /= 2;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    string to_string()
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << *this;
        string s;
        ss >> s;
        return s;
    }

    int sumof()
    {
        string s = to_string();
        int ans = 0;
        for (auto c : s)
            ans += c - '0';
        return ans;
    }

    /*</arpa>*/

    Int() : sign(1)
    {
    }

    Int(long long v)
    {
        *this = v;
    }

    Int(const string &s)
    {
        read(s);
    }

    void operator=(const Int &v)
    {
        sign = v.sign;
        a = v.a;
    }

    void operator=(long long v)
    {
        sign = 1;
        a.clear();
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -1, v = -v;
        for (; v > 0; v = v / base)
            a.push_back(v % base);
    }

    Int operator+(const Int &v) const
    {
        if (sign == v.sign)
        {
            Int res = v;
            for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int)max(a.size(), v.a.size()) || carry; ++i)
            {
                if (i == (int)res.a.size())
                    res.a.push_back(0);
                res.a[i] += carry + (i < (int)a.size() ? a[i] : 0);
                carry = res.a[i] >= base;
                if (carry)
                    res.a[i] -= base;
            }
            return res;
        }
        return *this - (-v);
    }

    Int operator-(const Int &v) const
    {
        if (sign == v.sign)
        {
            if (abs() >= v.abs())
            {
                Int res = *this;
                for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int)v.a.size() || carry; ++i)
                {
                    res.a[i] -= carry + (i < (int)v.a.size() ? v.a[i] : 0);
                    carry = res.a[i] < 0;
                    if (carry)
                        res.a[i] += base;
                }
                res.trim();
                return res;
            }
            return -(v - *this);
        }
        return *this + (-v);
    }

    void operator*=(int v)
    {
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -sign, v = -v;
        for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int)a.size() || carry; ++i)
        {
            if (i == (int)a.size())
                a.push_back(0);
            long long cur = a[i] * (long long)v + carry;
            carry = (int)(cur / base);
            a[i] = (int)(cur % base);
            //asm("divl %%ecx" : "=a"(carry), "=d"(a[i]) : "A"(cur), "c"(base));
        }
        trim();
    }

    Int operator*(int v) const
    {
        Int res = *this;
        res *= v;
        return res;
    }

    void operator*=(long long v)
    {
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -sign, v = -v;
        for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int)a.size() || carry; ++i)
        {
            if (i == (int)a.size())
                a.push_back(0);
            long long cur = a[i] * (long long)v + carry;
            carry = (int)(cur / base);
            a[i] = (int)(cur % base);
            //asm("divl %%ecx" : "=a"(carry), "=d"(a[i]) : "A"(cur), "c"(base));
        }
        trim();
    }

    Int operator*(long long v) const
    {
        Int res = *this;
        res *= v;
        return res;
    }

    friend pair<Int, Int> divmod(const Int &a1, const Int &b1)
    {
        int norm = base / (b1.a.back() + 1);
        Int a = a1.abs() * norm;
        Int b = b1.abs() * norm;
        Int q, r;
        q.a.resize(a.a.size());

        for (int i = a.a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            r *= base;
            r += a.a[i];
            int s1 = r.a.size() <= b.a.size() ? 0 : r.a[b.a.size()];
            int s2 = r.a.size() <= b.a.size() - 1 ? 0 : r.a[b.a.size() - 1];
            int d = ((long long)base * s1 + s2) / b.a.back();
            r -= b * d;
            while (r < 0)
                r += b, --d;
            q.a[i] = d;
        }

        q.sign = a1.sign * b1.sign;
        r.sign = a1.sign;
        q.trim();
        r.trim();
        return make_pair(q, r / norm);
    }

    Int operator/(const Int &v) const
    {
        return divmod(*this, v).first;
    }

    Int operator%(const Int &v) const
    {
        return divmod(*this, v).second;
    }

    void operator/=(int v)
    {
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -sign, v = -v;
        for (int i = (int)a.size() - 1, rem = 0; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            long long cur = a[i] + rem * (long long)base;
            a[i] = (int)(cur / v);
            rem = (int)(cur % v);
        }
        trim();
    }

    Int operator/(int v) const
    {
        Int res = *this;
        res /= v;
        return res;
    }

    int operator%(int v) const
    {
        if (v < 0)
            v = -v;
        int m = 0;
        for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            m = (a[i] + m * (long long)base) % v;
        return m * sign;
    }

    void operator+=(const Int &v)
    {
        *this = *this + v;
    }

    void operator-=(const Int &v)
    {
        *this = *this - v;
    }

    void operator*=(const Int &v)
    {
        *this = *this * v;
    }

    void operator/=(const Int &v)
    {
        *this = *this / v;
    }

    Int operator++()
    {
        *this += 1;
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator++(int)
    {
        Int temp = *this;
        *this += 1;
        return temp;
    }

    Int operator--()
    {
        *this -= 1;
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator--(int)
    {
        Int temp = *this;
        *this -= 1;
        return temp;
    }

    bool operator<(const Int &v) const
    {
        if (sign != v.sign)
            return sign < v.sign;
        if (a.size() != v.a.size())
            return a.size() * sign < v.a.size() * v.sign;
        for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (a[i] != v.a[i])
                return a[i] * sign < v.a[i] * sign;
        return false;
    }

    bool operator>(const Int &v) const
    {
        return v < *this;
    }

    bool operator<=(const Int &v) const
    {
        return !(v < *this);
    }

    bool operator>=(const Int &v) const
    {
        return !(*this < v);
    }

    bool operator==(const Int &v) const
    {
        return !(*this < v) && !(v < *this);
    }

    bool operator!=(const Int &v) const
    {
        return *this < v || v < *this;
    }

    void trim()
    {
        while (!a.empty() && !a.back())
            a.pop_back();
        if (a.empty())
            sign = 1;
    }

    bool isZero() const
    {
        return a.empty() || (a.size() == 1 && !a[0]);
    }

    Int operator-() const
    {
        Int res = *this;
        res.sign = -sign;
        return res;
    }

    Int abs() const
    {
        Int res = *this;
        res.sign *= res.sign;
        return res;
    }

    long long longValue() const
    {
        long long res = 0;
        for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            res = res * base + a[i];
        return res * sign;
    }

    friend Int gcd(const Int &a, const Int &b)
    {
        return b.isZero() ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }

    friend Int lcm(const Int &a, const Int &b)
    {
        return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
    }

    void read(const string &s)
    {
        sign = 1;
        a.clear();
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < (int)s.size() && (s[pos] == '-' || s[pos] == '+'))
        {
            if (s[pos] == '-')
                sign = -sign;
            ++pos;
        }

        for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= pos; i -= base_digits)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (int j = max(pos, i - base_digits + 1); j <= i; j++)
                x = x * 10 + s[j] - '0';
            a.push_back(x);
        }
        trim();
    }

    friend istream &operator>>(istream &stream, Int &v)
    {
        string s;
        stream >> s;
        v.read(s);
        return stream;
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const Int &v)
    {
        if (v.sign == -1)
            stream << '-';
        stream << (v.a.empty() ? 0 : v.a.back());
        for (int i = (int)v.a.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            stream << setw(base_digits) << setfill('0') << v.a[i];
        return stream;
    }

    static vector<int> convert_base(const vector<int> &a, int old_digits, int new_digits)
    {
        vector<long long> p(max(old_digits, new_digits) + 1);
        p[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < (int)p.size(); i++)
            p[i] = p[i - 1] * 10;
        vector<int> res;
        long long cur = 0;
        int cur_digits = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); i++)
        {
            cur += a[i] * p[cur_digits];
            cur_digits += old_digits;
            while (cur_digits >= new_digits)
            {
                res.push_back(int(cur % p[new_digits]));
                cur /= p[new_digits];
                cur_digits -= new_digits;
            }
        }
        res.push_back((int)cur);
        while (!res.empty() && !res.back())
            res.pop_back();
        return res;
    }

    typedef vector<long long> vll;

    static vll karatsubaMultiply(const vll &a, const vll &b)
    {
        int n = a.size();
        vll res(n + n);
        if (n <= 32)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    res[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
            return res;
        }

        int k = n >> 1;
        vll a1(a.begin(), a.begin() + k);
        vll a2(a.begin() + k, a.end());
        vll b1(b.begin(), b.begin() + k);
        vll b2(b.begin() + k, b.end());

        vll a1b1 = karatsubaMultiply(a1, b1);
        vll a2b2 = karatsubaMultiply(a2, b2);

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            a2[i] += a1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            b2[i] += b1[i];

        vll r = karatsubaMultiply(a2, b2);

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)a1b1.size(); i++)
            r[i] -= a1b1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)a2b2.size(); i++)
            r[i] -= a2b2[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)r.size(); i++)
            res[i + k] += r[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)a1b1.size(); i++)
            res[i] += a1b1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)a2b2.size(); i++)
            res[i + n] += a2b2[i];
        return res;
    }

    Int operator*(const Int &v) const
    {
        vector<int> a6 = convert_base(this->a, base_digits, 6);
        vector<int> b6 = convert_base(v.a, base_digits, 6);

        vll a(a6.begin(), a6.end());
        vll b(b6.begin(), b6.end());

        while (a.size() < b.size())
            a.push_back(0);
        while (b.size() < a.size())
            b.push_back(0);
        while (a.size() & (a.size() - 1))
            a.push_back(0), b.push_back(0);

        vll c = karatsubaMultiply(a, b);
        Int res;
        res.sign = sign * v.sign;
        for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int)c.size(); i++)
        {
            long long cur = c[i] + carry;
            res.a.push_back((int)(cur % 1000000));
            carry = (int)(cur / 1000000);
        }
        res.a = convert_base(res.a, 6, base_digits);
        res.trim();
        return res;
    }

    //Added part.

    friend Int max(const Int &a, const Int &b)
    {
        if (a < b)
        {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }

    friend Int max(const Int &a, const int32_t &B)
    {
        Int b = B;
        return max(a, b);
    }

    friend Int max(const Int &a, const int64_t &B)
    {
        Int b = B;
        return max(a, b);
    }

    friend Int min(const Int &a, const Int &b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            return b;
        }
        return a;
    }

    friend Int min(const Int &a, const int32_t &B)
    {
        Int b = B;
        return min(a, b);
    }

    friend Int min(const Int &a, const int64_t &B)
    {
        Int b = B;
        return min(a, b);
    }

    friend Int pow(const Int &a, const Int &b)
    {
        Int _c = 1;
        Int _b = b;
        Int _a = a;
        while (_b != 0)
        {
            if (_b % 2)
            {
                _c *= _a;
            }
            _a *= _a;
            _b /= 2;
        }
        return _c;
    }

    friend Int pow(const Int &a, const int32_t &B)
    {
        Int b = B;
        return pow(a, b);
    }

    friend Int pow(const Int &a, const int64_t &B)
    {
        Int b = B;
        return pow(a, b);
    }

    friend Int sqrt(Int a)
    {
        Int x0 = a, x1 = (a + 1) / 2;
        while (x1 < x0)
        {
            x0 = x1;
            x1 = (x1 + a / x1) / 2;
        }
        return x0;
    }
};
/*
  #######################   THE   BIG   INT   ##########################
  ######################################################################
*/
```